# general solutions of differential system with non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition

Solve the initial value problem $\bar{x}^{\prime}=A \bar{x}, \bar{x}(0)=\bar{x}_0$, where
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -2 \\
-1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad \bar{x}_0=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

I know since this matrix A is not diagonalizable, so we use matrix decomposition into invariant subspaces.\

The characteristic equation is
$$
p_A(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)+2(1-\lambda)+2-(2-\lambda)=-\lambda^2(\lambda-2)=0
$$
The generalized eigenvectors for $\lambda=0$ are given by the null space to
$$
A^2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & -2 \\
2 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
which has a basis $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$. The eigenvalue for $\lambda=2$ are given by the null space to
$$
A-2 I=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \\
-1 & 1 & -3
\end{array}\right)
$$
which gives the eigenvector $(1,1,0)$.

BUT from here I don't understand how to get the general solution given below by the answer and the initial value part:

\

The general solution is
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \bar{x}(t)=(I+t A)\left(c_1(0,1,1)+c_2(1,0,1)\right)+c_3 e^{2 t}(1,1,0) \\
&=c_1(0,1,1)+c_2((1,0,1)-2 t(0,1,1))+c_3 e^{2 t}(1,1,0)
\end{aligned}
$$
The initial value $(-1,1,0)=(0,1,1)-(1,0,1)$ is a generalized eigenvector for $\lambda=0$ so we get the solution $\bar{x}(t)=(I+t A)(-1,1,0)=(-1,1,0)+t(0,2,2)$.

Thanks in advance! Much appreciate your time :D

Comment: here is the [solution](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/dec_8_2022.pdf)

Comment: thank you so much！！！